# Using MD5 and Password hash function when storing in database

Tags: php, encryption, pdo, hash

If I have this PHP script for a login system:

```
    $user = $_POST['user_name'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['user_pass']);

    require_once("connection_file.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_table WHERE user_n = :us AND user_p = :password";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':us', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if($result)
    {
        //echo $msg = "user exist";
        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        {
            session_start();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $hash = password_hash($row['user_pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                if(password_verify($row['user_pass'], $hash))
                {
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['user_role'];
                    header("Location: homepage.php");
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Wrong credentials";
        header("Location: login_page.php");
    }
```

And as you see I am already saving my password in database as `MD5` and I am using `$pass = md5($_POST['user_pass']);` to verify if the text input by the user is equal to `MD5` hash.

1. Now my question is should I use the `password_hash` and `password_verify` as I am using in this script ? Or using `MD5` would be enough ?
2. And my second question is can I save passwords in database using the hash string result or it is okay to use the md5 one?

Comment: Don't use MD5 it's an old and weak hash.

Comment: But it is correct when I use the password_hash part of the script ? Why you downvoted me ?

Comment: I didn't downvote and yes use `password_hash`

Comment: okay but why people downvoting ? What is wrong with my question, this my first question that I've been downvoted, it is really demostating

Comment: So you are using password_hash but asking whether it's ok to use md5 instead. this question makes no sense to me. NO, if you really need the answer.

Comment: I mean in my question if I can use a combination of them to be more secure, or just using hash is good enough

Comment: If you try to use a combination the odds are you'll end up making it far **less** secure.

Comment: Well you choose a HIGHLY unclear way to ask. The answer is no.

Comment: If I want to modify the script and I saved in my db a hashed password instead a normal string, in the sql query should I just select the username then I will go into `if(password_verify...)` to see if the password is equal to the hash or it is mandatory to select username and password in the query

Comment: Just try it and see, whether it's ever possible.

Comment: I tried it and it works, but is it safe ?

Comment: (Despite everyone's reflex to downvote this, it's a question about password hash migration. They already know not to use MD5.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should migrate to the new API and never use MD5 for this purpose again, immediately.

---

If you're not using `password_hash()`/`password_verify()` and want to [migrate your code to a more secure method, seamlessly](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes):

1. Add a column to your user accounts table, called `legacy_password` (or equivalent).
2. Calculate the bcrypt hash of **the existing MD5 hashes** and store them in the database (setting `legacy_password` to `TRUE`).
3. Modify your authentication code to handle the legacy flag.

When a user attempts to login, first check if the `legacy_password` flag is set. If it is, first pre-hash their password with MD5, then use this prehashed value in place of their password. Afterwards, *recalculate* the bcrypt hash and store the new hash in the database, disabling the `legacy_password` flag in the process. A very loose example in PHP 7+ follows:

```
/**
 * This is example code. Please feel free to use it for reference but don't just copy/paste it.
 *
 * @param string $username Unsafe user-supplied data: The username
 * @param string $password Unsafe user-supplied data: The password
 * @return int The primary key for that user account
 * @throws InvalidUserCredentialsException
 */
public function authenticate(string $username, string $password): int
{
    // Database lookup
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT userid, passwordhash, legacy_password FROM user_accounts WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$username]);
    $stored = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$stored) {
        // No such user, throw an exception
        throw new InvalidUserCredentialsException();
    }
    if ($stored['legacy_password']) {
        // This is the legacy password upgrade code
        if (password_verify(md5($password), $stored['passwordhash'])) {
            $newhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE user_accounts SET passwordhash = ?, legacy_password = FALSE WHERE userid = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$newhash, $stored['userid']]);

            // Return the user ID (integer)
            return $stored['userid'];
        }
    } elseif (password_verify($password, $stored['passwordhash'])) {
        // This is the general purpose upgrade code e.g. if a future version of PHP upgrades to Argon2
        if (password_needs_rehash($stored['passwordhash'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
            $newhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE user_accounts SET passwordhash = ? WHERE userid = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$newhash, $stored['userid']]);
        }
        // Return the user ID (integer)
        return $stored['userid'];
    }
    // When all else fails, throw an exception
    throw new InvalidUserCredentialsException();
}
```

Usage:

```
try {
    $userid = $this->authenticate($username, $password);
    // Update the session state
    // Redirect to the post-authentication landing page
} catch (InvalidUserCredentialsException $e) {
    // Log the failure
    // Redirect to the login form
}
```

Proactively upgrading legacy hashes is a security win over an opportunistic strategy (rehashing when the user logs in, but leave the insecure hashes in the database for inactive users): With a proactive strategy, if your server gets compromised before everyone logs in again, their passwords are already using an acceptable algorithm (bcrypt, in the example code).

The above example code is also available in [Bcrypt-SHA-384](https://gist.github.com/paragonie-scott/66469d391deef2e3b875) flavor.

---

Also, this has nothing to do with [encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).